# adding home screen shortcuts on android 4.0 ics

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, shortcut

I have a few apps that install shortcuts on the user's home screen and it works as it should on all versions except ics. The shortcut is placed on the home screen in ics but when I click on it is says "application not installed". I wanted to know if anyone else had this problem before and if they fixed it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AndroidDevelopers">
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".HomeActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Sounds like a manifest problem. Lets see :-)

Comment: I added the manifest but like I said it works on all versions of android except 4.0/ics

Comment: I've downloaded other apps that have home screen shoutcuts and see the same problem. I think this may be a bug

Answer (score 0):

Try giving fully qualified name of the activity